# Character (picturebox) collision with different picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox, collision

I'm going a Simple C# game I'm using A picture box as my character the movement code work but now i have another problem i have barriers made of other picture boxes and i have written code with would move it to starting position but i don't know how to tell barrier if character will touch a barer move it to starting position

i would see it like that if on the barrier if picturebox1.enter\ character
                                              movetostart()\my position detection

Comment: FYI, the name of the language is "C#", not "C Sharp".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's too late but you can try this

under keypress event type the following:

if (picturebox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(barrier.Bounds))

```
        {

             picturebox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        }
```